# Using WallpaperManager and toPhone

Tags: android, wallpaper

I have Multiple Images and if i use `WallpaperManager` then it will set the wallpaper to what it is said to set wallpaper as. How am i able to use toPhone and WallpaperManager?

Java file (if needed):

```
 package hd.wallpaper.abs;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Main extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView display;
    int toPhone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hd__wallpapers);
        toPhone = R.drawable.eye;

        display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVdisplay);
        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage1);
        ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage2);
        ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage3);
        ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage4);
        ImageView image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage5);
        ImageView image6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage7);
        Button setWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setwallpaperbutton);
        image1.setOnClickListener(this);
        image2.setOnClickListener(this);
        image3.setOnClickListener(this);
        image4.setOnClickListener(this);
        image5.setOnClickListener(this);
        image6.setOnClickListener(this);
        setWall.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.IVimage1:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.i1);
        toPhone = R.drawable.i1;
        break;
        case R.id.IVimage2:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.i2);
        toPhone = R.drawable.i2;
        break;
        case R.id.IVimage3:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.i3);
            toPhone =R.drawable.i3;
            break;
        case R.id.IVimage4:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.i3);
            toPhone =R.drawable.i3;
            break;
        case R.id.IVimage5:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.i3);
            toPhone =R.drawable.i3;
            break;
        case R.id.IVimage7:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.i3);
            toPhone =R.drawable.solar;
            break;
        case R.id.setwallpaperbutton:
            final WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
             = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            final int fullWidth = myWallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumWidth();
            final int fullHeight = myWallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumHeight();
            try {
             myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.i1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        }

    }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11953435/940096) will give some idea. Have a look at that.

Comment: I have looked at this before i posted. As you can see in my Java i do have the code wrttin correctly and still problems with the app.

Answer (score 0):

```
case R.id.BsetWallpaper:
            InputStream first = getResources().openRawResource(toPhone);
      Bitmap close= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(first);      
      try{
          getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(close);
      }catch (IOException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

hope help u.!

Answer (score 0):

in you code

```
final WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
final int fullWidth = myWallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumWidth();
final int fullHeight = myWallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumHeight();
try {
myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.i1);
```

each time you are setting **R.drawable.i1** as wallpaper just change this with **toPhone** and it should solve your problem.