# Set wallpaper using bitmap in android

Tags: android, bitmap, int, wallpaper

When setting the wallpaper I'm using an int and then I'm converting it into a bitmap with `decodestream` but the wallpaper is still not set.

Here is my code

```
InputStream y = getResources().openRawResource(friendship);
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(y);

try {               
    getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(b);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Wallpaper Set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `setWallpaper()` is deprecated. Instead use WallpaperManager http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953359/using-wallpapermanager-in-android-to-set-wallpaper

Answer (score 0):

Is the permission `SET_WALLPAPER` set in the manifest file? [Android docs link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SET_WALLPAPER)

Further more, the method that you are using is deprecated. You should be using [WallpaperManager apis](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29)